# GoDaddy SSL Certificate installation in tomcat... No certificate matches private key

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate, keytool, pkcs#12

Generate the Tomcat KeyStore

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore
    tomcat.keystore
```

Generate the Certificate KeyStore

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcatCert -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

Generate the Keys

```
keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file csr.txt -keystore tomcat.keystore -storepass pa$$word
```

Merge certs

```
cat mydomain.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > combinedcerts
```

Create P12 keystore

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tomcat.keystore -destkeystore tomcatkey.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass pa$$word
```

Generate PEM

```
openssl pkcs12 -in tomcatkey.p12 -out tomcatkey.pem -nodes
```

Exporting remaining CRT files to keystore...

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -in combinedcerts -inkey tomcatkey.pem -out new.tomcat.keystore -name tomcat -passout pass:pa$$word
```

And in this last step I'm getting the following error: "**No certificate matches private key**"

This same steps worked a couple of years ago, server is the same... only JDK is 8u131 vs 8u45 from before.

Can someone guide me on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generate the Tomcat KeyStore

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore
tomcat.keystore
```

No. This step creates the keystore file all right, but more importantly it creates the keypair, of type RSA.

> Generate the Certificate KeyStore

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcatCert -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

No. This step does not 'generate the certificate keystore', whatever that is supposed to be. It does nothing except create another keypair, under another alias, in the *same* keystore, and the alias remains unused throughout the rest of the procedure. It is identical by inspection to the previous step, with the exception of the alias change, which is pointless, and the missing key size, which make make it useless. Omit.

> Generate the Keys

```
keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file csr.txt -keystore tomcat.keystore -storepass pa$$word
```

You already generated the keys in the first step. This step generates the Certificate Signing Request (CSR).

> Merge certs

```
cat mydomain.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > combinedcerts
```

There's a step missing here, where you submitted the CSR and got it signed. Presumably the results of this process were mydomain.crt and the Godaddy bundle file.

> Create P12 keystore

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tomcat.keystore -destkeystore tomcatkey.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass pa$$word
```

Why? You could have used -storetype PKCS12 at step 1 and following, if you wanted a P12 keystore. And there is a step missing here, where you import the concatenated certificates back into the original keystore.

> Generate PEM

```
openssl pkcs12 -in tomcatkey.p12 -out tomcatkey.pem -nodes
```

Why?

> Exporting remaining CRT files to keystore...

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -in combinedcerts -inkey tomcatkey.pem -out new.tomcat.keystore -name tomcat -passout pass:pa$$word
```

Why?

I don't know why you're doing these OpenSSL steps. Tomcat can already handle either `tomcat.keystore` or `tomcat.p12` as they already are.

> And in this last step I'm getting the following error: "No certificate matches private key"

I don't know why you're doing most of these steps. You're never using the  `tomcatCert` alias, and you're putting an already perfectly adequate `tomcat.keystore` file through not one but three further pointless steps.

> This same steps worked a couple of years ago, server is the same... only JDK is 8u131 vs 8u45 from before.

I doubt it. They are mislabelled, redundant, incomplete, and totally incoherent. More probably somebody just flailed around helplessly until something worked and then wrote down as much as they could remember. There is no need to use the OpenSSL tool at all. All you need is:

1. Generate the keypair: `keytool -genkey`.
2. Generate the CSR: `keytool -certreq`.
3. Get the CSR signed.
4. Concatenate the certificates, your newly signed certificate first, then the bundle.
5. Import the concatenated file into the same keystore using the same alias as at (1) and (2).

Comment: Hi, Can you explain this? "Concatenate the certificates, your newly signed certificate first, then the bundle." Thanks :D

Comment: If you concatenate the certs file, it only means they will have the same alias. But how about the root alias and intermed? Aren't they separated from the end-cert?